# iPad browser that looks like desktop to website

Tags: ipad

There are sites that sense the iPad is a mobile device. For example, Spotify. It will refuse to play in an iPad browser, while it works just fine on a laptop. It appears to be sensing what browser is in use, as do many sites that push a mobile version instead of the standard site.

Is there any workaround for this?

Additional note - Thanks for the answers so far. The desktop version requires Flash. This may kill the Spotify success, but great for sites that don't use flash, so I hope this Q&A helps others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Use a browser that allows you to change the user agent. Two examples are:

- [Atomic Web Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/atomic-web-browser-browse/id347929410)

[image]

- [Terra](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/terra-web-browser-tabs-full/id394704159).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you already have Chorme for iPad, you can use its "Request Desktop Site" feature:

[image]

Here's [how it works on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702453/how-does-chromes-request-desktop-site-option-work), I'm assuming it's very similar on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS now has a request desktop site feature. Use that or view it on a browser that lets you change the user agent.
[image]